# How to compile scala sources via maven integration in intellij idea?

Tags: scala, maven-2, intellij-idea, circumflex-orm

I am learning circumflex orm and using maven with idea for the first time. I expected that my sources in `src` will compile to `build` directory. But it doesn't happen. And if I specify `sourceDirectory` and `outputDirectory` like `${basedir}/src` or `${project.basedir}/build` I get intellij idea's inspections that such folders doesn't exist (sic!)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>C2Probe</groupId>
    <artifactId>C2Probe</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>build</outputDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ru.circumflex</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cx-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cx.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>configure</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>cfg</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <cx.version>1.1</cx.version>
        <orm.connection.driver>org.postgresql.Driver</orm.connection.driver>
        <orm.connection.url>jdbc:postgresql:mydb</orm.connection.url>
        <orm.connection.username>myuser</orm.connection.username>
        <orm.connection.password>mypass</orm.connection.password>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.circumflex</groupId>
            <artifactId>circumflex-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${cx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

What should I do to compile my sources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>greet.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

Thanks http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/bryan_weber/scala_and_maven_with_maven.html for good tutorial.

Comment: Now you should use the [scala-maven-plugin](https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin).

Answer (score 2):

The Maven convention is that the compiled classes are put into `target/classes`. Unless you have a very good reason to do it differently, it is better (and much less painful) to stick to the convention.

Comment: Is programming in scala a good reason or I should put scala soursces in src/main/java? And if I follow this convention than I must remove "sourceDirectory" and "outputDirectory" tags? (I did it and got "Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date" yet again).

Comment: @Jeriho, I have no experience with Scala, but since AFAIK you need a different compiler for Scala source, I would put them under `src/main/scala`. You may need to configure that source directory explicitly in Maven though.